# Flink configurations to avoid uploading extenal jars every time submit job

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn, flink-streaming

Does Flink has configurations to avoid uploading extenal jars every time submit job, like `spark.yarn.archive` in spark-submit?

I know ways to deal with external jars like answers in: [How to Reference the External Jar in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784051/how-to-reference-the-external-jar-in-flink). Such as fat jar, Copying jars to `$FLINK/lib`, `-yt` configuration, but they are not flexible or convenient enough.

Comment: At the moment Flink does not have a similar feature such as `spark.yarn.archive` which allows you to host the framework's binaries on HDFS. Instead, Flink assumes that your binaries are locally available to upload them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice Flink has an issue [FLINK-13938](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-13938) to resolve this, and the improve haved been merged in recent version 1.11.0.

A final submission command could be issued like following.

```
./bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -d \
-yD yarn.provided.lib.dirs=hdfs://myhdfs/flink/lib,hdfs://myhdfs/flink/plugins \
examples/streaming/WindowJoin.jar
```